# JetPack comment threads are displaying above comment box?

Tags: comments, css, plugin-jetpack

As you can see in the attached image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt5IZ.png) my JetPack comments are rendering above the Discuss box. How do I go about moving them down? When I look in Chrome Inspector there doesn't even seem to be any Class or ID for me to latch onto to bring them down. In my theme I am using the following code to place the entire comment form:

```
<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You should really pick one or the other.

They are both designed to replace your existing commenting system and both take over the commenting functionality.  Discuss does it by inserting javascript and jetpack uses an iframe.

Comment: are you suggesting I have inserted the wrong code in my template?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question.  Are you trying to use Jetpack comments or Discuss comments?

Comment: Trying to use JetPack

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `<?php comment_form() ?>` to show jetpack comment form... this one is probably located inside your comments.php file. Just move it above the comment list tag and you got what you're lopking for